# Redirect to a Controller Action from Javascript code in View in Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
$this->registerJS(
'var ok = confirm("File already exists!! Do you want to overwrite file");
    if(ok)
    {
       "'.Url::toRoute('default/over-write?id=1').'";
    }
    else
    {
       "'.Url::toRoute('default/over-write?id=0').'";
    };',View::POS_READY);
```

The Url call is supposed to call actionOverWrite() in DefaultController. But this is not happening. How to call action from view?

Comment: Use this : window.location.href='http://www.your-url.com';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try this

```
$this->registerJS(
'var url = "'.Url::toRoute('default/over-write?id=').'";
    if(confirm("File already exists!! Do you want to overwrite file"))
    {
       window.location.href = url + '1';
    }
    else
    {
       window.location.href = url + '0';
    };',View::POS_READY);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply try :

```
$this->registerJS('
    var ok = confirm("File already exists!! Do you want to overwrite file");
    window.location.replace("'.Url::toRoute('default/over-write').'" + "?id=" + (ok ? 1 : 0));
', View::POS_READY);
```

Read more about js redirection : 
[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page)